# Instanciation of class to be tested in test class in Java

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, dependency-injection

What is the best practice in order to get an instance of the class to be tested in the test class?
Is it better to instantiate it manually with a

```java
ClassToBeTested classToBeTested = new ClassToBeTested();
```

inside the test-class

OR

get it from the Spring context, like this:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/services-test-config.xml"})
public class MySericeTest {

  @Autowired
  MyService service;
...

}
```

Comment: Does it have any dependencies? If it does, the second case will provide them for you. If not, or you're willing to provide them yourself, either will work.

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept, glad you found the answer helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple rule in programming, that can guide such questions:

*you don't do something because you can, but because it makes sense to do it*.

Meaning: you always strive to write the most minimalistic, simplistic code that solves your problem.

So when

```
ClassToBeTested classToBeTested = new ClassToBeTested();
```

is sufficient for your testcase, and gives you all you need to write a nice test, then you use that.

If you need something that you get "easier" from that annotation-based DI approach, *then* you use that approach.

Having said that, there are also conventions. When the "typical" thing that most programmers would do ... is to use the annotation-approach, then that is what you should use.

Answer (score 0):

Better try to use auto wiring to be aligned with more clean and test friendly code and future change.

using "new" can be problematice in future but auto-wiring may save you